# PHP 'power of' results in parse error

Tags: php, math, parse-error, php-parse-error

The following code:

```
5 ** 2
```

results in this error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '*'
```

And I have no idea why. Can anyone help me?

Comment: That is not how you square numbers in PHP. Use [`pow()`](http://php.net/pow) instead. `pow(5, 2)`.

Comment: Your error is because `**` isn't a thing in PHP.

Comment: PHP 5.6 (upcoming) [will have an `**` exponentiation operator](http://www.php.net//manual/en/migration56.new-features.php) but for now you have to `pow()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pow()` function. Get returned value of `pow(5,2)`

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pow.php

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this:

```
5 ** 2
```

When you should be doing this in PHP using the [`pow()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) function:

```
echo pow(5,2);
```